# 2 beginner calculus questions - Help needed

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation

I am in an online bridge course starting my masters after not doing calculus for 12 years.  My professor does not reply to emails, online "office hours" ive been told to email him since we have moved past this, but he still doesn't reply.  So I am posting homework that I simply do not understand and have failed in the internet to find answers.

1st: Find the derivative of

$$f_k(x)=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

2nd: Find the derivative of

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Assuming that you can differentiate an infinite sum term-wise.
Based on its derivative, can you guess what function $f(x)$ is?

3rd: Find  the derivitive of $$f(p) = \ln\left(\prod_{i=1}^np^{x_i}(1-p)^{1-x_i} \right)$$

Between 1 and 2: I don't understand how the derivative would change based upon the summation end changing from a real number to infinity.

For the 3rd, I feel like my basic algebra is failing me because I get $$\ln\left(\prod(p-p)^1\right)$$  which I am very certain is not correct.

Any help would be appreciated to understand what is going on here and what I'm missing.  Thanks in advance for my help on my first post.

Comment: Thanks for the edit SMA.D, been a long night.

Comment: There is an interesting property that if $f(x) = \sum_{a} g(x)$ and $a$ is  independent of $x$, then $f'(x) = \sum_{a} g'(x)$. This should give you a hint on how to solve the first two problems. The second problem  is the Taylor Series expansion of $e^x - 1$. <br>. As to why the infinite sum differs from sum up to a constant value, think of it intuitively. The sum of a series till a constant factor for non-infinite terms can only be a non-infinite result, but the same system can lead to an infinite sum (think of the difference between $\sum_a^\inf 1$ and $$\sum_a^k 1)

Comment: But the questions imply the derivatives should be different, but all that has changed is the upper limit.  How does that change the derivative?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that info, so I edited my previous comment... Basically, think of the sequence $\sum_0^{\infty} 1$ and the sequence $\sum_0^k 1$. The derivative of both the sum terms is 0, but if you sum and then differentiate them, the second one is still 0, while the first one becomes undefined (what is the differential of infinity?)

Comment: For the third one, your simplification is indeed incorrect... $p^x(1-p)^{1-x} = p^{x(1-x)/(1-x)} (1-p)^{1-x} =  (p^{x/1-x} (1-p)) ^ {1-x}\neq (p-p)^1$. The correct simplification for that would be to use log properties to break the log into two pieces, and use the make the product of terms inside the logs as a summation of the powers (again use properties of logs)

Comment: in number 3, is $p$ the variable?

Answer (score 3):

$(1) $First, note that the first term in this series is a constant real number with no variable in it. The remaining terms will be a function of $x$...

$$\sum_{n=0}^{k} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{x^0}{0!} + \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{1}{1} + \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Second, recall that the derivative of sums or differences is the sums or differences of the derivatives. Hence,

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^{k} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{d}{dx} [1 + \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{x^n}{n!}] = \frac{d}{dx} [1] + \frac{d}{dx}[\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{x^n}{n!}] = \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Now you differentiate with respect to $x$. You may be wondering "What do I do with $n$?" The answer is that you treat $n$ as though it is a constant. Note that $n$ is an index that tells you how many terms are in the series as well as how the constants in each term differ from one term to the next. So,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n!} \frac{d}{dx}x^n = \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n!} n x^{(n-1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{n x^{(n-1)}}{n!}$$

Now, note that there is an opportunity to simplify this fraction if we expand the factorial some...

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{n x^{(n-1)}}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{n x^{(n-1)}}{n(n-1)!} = \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{x^{(n-1)}}{(n-1)!}$$

Thus,

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^{k} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{x^{(n-1)}}{(n-1)!}$$

---

$(2)$ You are correct about nothing changing between $1$ and $2$. The reasoning is the same, only now it translates to a sum over infinite terms. Nice intuition!

Comment: Thank you, this part makes much more sense now.

Comment: no problem. in #$3$, is $p$ the variable? Confused as to what $x_i$ is

Comment: RyRy if you look at the beginning of the equation and see f(p), that is saying function f being manipulated by variable p.  You will see below the product sign the i=0, this means the value that has a little i on it is the value that is sequencing from 0 to n, whatever n may be.  So while p is a variable, $$x_i$$ is also going to change with every iteration of the product series from 1 to n.